# Regular expression to parse configuration file

Tags: javascript, regex

im using javascript to read in the file

example would be

```
#########################
#####################
#sominfo
#some info
path = thisPath
file = thisFile.txt  #this file may need a comment
```

im looking for a regular expression to return either

```
[[path, thisPath],[file, thisFile.txt]]
```

or

```
{path: thisPath,file: thisFile.txt}  <-- which i'll probably have to do after the fact
```

Comment: All the other lines start with a "#"?

Comment: Is `file` always on the line after `path` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`str.replace` is your tool of choice for regex-based parsing:

```js
conf = 
    "#########################\n"+
    "#sominfo\n"+
    "\t\t#some info = baz\n"+
    "\n\n#\n\n\n"+
    "   path = thisPath\n"+
    "file \t= thisFile.txt  #this file may need a comment\n"+
    "foo=bar#comment\n"+
    "  empty=";

data = {}
conf.replace(/^(?!\s*#)\s*(\S+)\s*=\s*([^\s#]*)/gm, function(_, key, val) {
  data[key] = val
});

document.write(JSON.stringify(data))
```

Comment: thanks so much i spent a while on this to come to the conclusion that i have no idea how regex works

Answer (score 3):

`\S+` matches one or more non-space characters. `(?! *#)` negative lookahead asserts that there isn't a character `#` present at the start.

```
var re = /^(?! *#)(\S+) *= *(\S+)/gm

var results = [];

while (m = re.exec(str)) {
   var matches = [];
   matches.push(m[1]);
   matches.push(m[2]);
   results.push(matches);
}

console.log(results) //=> [ [ 'path', 'thisPath' ], [ 'file', 'thisFile.txt' ] ]
```

[**Regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/aM4iH1/1) | [**Working Demo**](https://eval.in/282298)

Comment: or `^(?!#)(\S+) *= *(.+?)(?= +#|$)`

Comment: But what if there are other lines line `something = something`. Wouldn't be safe to write `(path|file)`

Comment: i think the one before = is the path and after `=` is the filename.

Comment: or `/^(?!#)(\S*(?:file|path)\s*) *= *(\S*(?:file|path)\S*)/gmi`